# python multipling two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have got two dictionaries:

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2}
stock = {"banana": 6,"apple": 0,}
```

How I can get sum of combining values from 1 and 2 dictionary (4*6+2*0 - in this example)?

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the two dictionary don't share the same keys?

Comment: I made a request that multiplication should be added to `collections.Counter` but it didn't go through: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/python-ideas/-HYxQK6cbps

Comment: (probably for the better though) although this would have been a good example to use

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2}
>>> stock = {"banana": 6,"apple": 0}
>>> {k: prices[k] * stock[k] for k in prices.viewkeys() & stock.viewkeys()}
{'banana': 24, 'apple': 0}
```

Comment: 4 answers in 5 seconds. Oh. My. God. (btw you were first jamylak ;))

Comment: It's that kind of low-hanging-fruit question. Irresistible not to have a try. They shouldn't really be allowed.

Comment: I don't like viewkeys much because it's 2.7 specific

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a little shorter and neater than the other solutions.

```
>>> prices = {"banana": 4, "apple": 2}
>>> stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0}
>>> {key: value * stock.get(key, 0) for key, value in prices.items()}
{'banana': 24, 'apple': 0}
```

Use `prices.iteritems()` in Python 2.

This avoids creating a new set, and technically only uses one dictionary lookup. If you just want the sum, use this:

```
>>> sum(value * stock.get(key, 0) for key, value in prices.items())
24
```

Comment: It's different from the solution by @Martijn and me since it also multiplies keys that exist only in `prices`

Comment: @jamylak granted. I posted this solution mainly because of my aversion to the [`&`](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ae-Jy6EBy00/T06tOwXz80I/AAAAAAAAbug/O3SxiaOSzqU/s1600/4dandforsand.jpg) symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Without assuming the keys are identical

```
sum(prices[k] * stock.get(k, 0) for k in prices)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the intersection of the keys:

```
mult = {}

for key in prices.viewkeys() & stock.viewkeys():
    mult[key] = prices[key] * stock[key]
```

This can be simplified to a dict comprehension:

```
mult = {key: prices[key] * stock[key] for key in prices.viewkeys() & stock.viewkeys()}
```

This uses the [`dict.viewkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) method (`dict.keys()` in Python 3), which acts like a `set`; the `&` operator acts like a intersection operator on sets and gives you all keys that are present in *both* dictionaries.

To sum the total stock, use the `sum()` function:

```
total_stock = sum(prices[key] * stock[key] for key in prices.viewkeys() & stock.viewkeys())
```

Demo:

```
>>> prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2}
>>> stock = {"banana": 6,"apple": 0}
>>> {key: prices[key] * stock[key] for key in prices.viewkeys() & stock.viewkeys()}
{'banana': 24, 'apple': 0}
>>> sum(prices[key] * stock[key] for key in prices.viewkeys() & stock.viewkeys())
24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2}
>>> stock = {"banana": 6,"apple": 0}
>>> sum( prices[k] * stock[k] for k in stock)
24
```

Comment: sum( prices[k] * stock[k] for k in stock) great answear.

Answer (score 0):

```
prices = {"banana": 4,"apple": 2} 
stock = {"banana": 6,"apple": 0,}
t=0
for i in prices:
      t+=prices[i]*stock[i]
print t
```

Comment: `dict.keys()` is not required, an iteration over a dict returns it's keys only.